# Connecting array elements with lines

Tags: support, mathjax

This is admittedly a bit of an abuse of MathJax, but I'm trying to use it to draw lines to connect dots within a rectangular array.

I can easily get an array of dots, but I can't figure out a way to draw lines connecting them:

$$
\begin{matrix}
\bullet&\bullet&\bullet\\
\bullet&\bullet&\bullet\\
\bullet&\bullet&\bullet\\
\end{matrix}
$$

I tried horizontal and vertical strikeouts, but they don't span from one array element to the next, and they also overlap the corners:

$$\require{enclose}
\begin{matrix}
\enclose{verticalstrike,horizontalstrike}{\bullet}&\enclose{verticalstrike,horizontalstrike}{\bullet}&\bullet&\\
\enclose{verticalstrike,horizontalstrike}{\bullet}&\enclose{verticalstrike,horizontalstrike}{\bullet}&\bullet\\
\bullet&\bullet&\bullet\\
\end{matrix}
$$

I'm trying to accomplish something like this:

[image]

Is this possible using MathJax?

Comment: Sorry, you have the wrong website. This site, meta.math.stackexchange.com, is for discussing math.stackexchange.com.

Comment: @GerryMyerson I understand that, but there seem to be many other MathJax-related questions here, and there's even a tag for them. How does this question differ from those?

Comment: A question about how MathJax is implemented on math.stackexchange.com could be on-topic. That's the difference. Have you considered tex.stackexchange? I don't know anything about that site, but it might be worth a look.

Comment: @GerryMyerson Thanks for the clarification. I have edited my question accordingly.

Comment: Editing out the reference to Puzzling.se doesn't suddenly make your question on-topic for meta.math.se

Comment: @GerryMyerson I will check out Tex.SE as well.

Comment: @GerryMyerson For the most part, MathJax is off-topic on [tex.se] since it's not TeX or its variants.

Comment: @GerryMyerson I understand, and will try elsewhere. However, if this question had originally appeared here in its current form, would you have thought it off-topic?

Comment: Even in its current form, it doesn't relate to math.se, so (in my opinion) it's off-topic on meta.math.se.

Comment: Have you looked at the huge Mathjax thread on this meta? amscd (for commutative diagrams) is likely as good as it's going to get (but would leave gaps), unless you spend hours going crazy with v and hskips or some other terrible thing.

Comment: Just use Inkscape, GIMP, Paint, whatever you want. MathJaX simply isn't designed for this. Maybe you'll manage to get what you want, but it will be through horrible tricks that will take hours to achieve when it would take minutes to produce the same picture with usual drawing software.

Comment: This is somewhat related: [Is there a way to draw a graph (vertices & edges) in LaTeX on this website?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/11049/is-there-a-way-to-draw-a-graph-vertices-edges-in-latex-on-this-website). (Ant try to have a look at other posts shown among linked and related questions in the sidebar.)

Comment: Some very simple graphs can probably be drawn as commutative diagrams. It is possible to create some simple commutative diagrams using MathJax, but the possibilities are rather limited: [How to draw a commutative diagram?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/2324/how-to-draw-a-commutative-diagram). [This answer](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/a/12372) links a website where you can use xypic syntax to create commutative diagrams online. (And then you can embed them as a picture.)